# Git repository - switch project local repo and push it to existing git repo

Tags: java, git, repository

Lets say i have inited new repo onto my eclipse workspace project "Myproject". I have created a user and a repository to bitbucket.org/myuser/MyRepoHoldingMyProject. Now unfortunatelly i messed up "Myproject" and i created a new project "MySecond" . What is the best way to push "MySecond" to MyRepoHoldingMyProject, to overwrite its files. Do i have to delete the repo and make a new one, and then init "MySecond" ? Or will it work when i just repleace the content and name of the "Myproject" ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to rename your remote repo to other name e.g. `MyRepoHoldingMyProject_backup` and create a new repo `MyRepoHoldingMyProject`.
Doing so you will not lost commit history or may be some valuable code.

After that just:

`git init` in `MySecond` project root directory, if you have not done it yet

`git git remote add origin link_to_new_repo`

`git add -A` check with `git status` which files were added

`git commit -m 'Initial commit'`

`git pull`

`git push`

Comment: link_to_new_repo - is the exact same link what was in my old repo. Thats the problem. I did init and added remote with it, and when i push, it says that already up to date, even when it acutually isnt, because its a bit different project

Comment: probably you need to add `MySecond` files to git, commit them and than push. answer updated.